# Androidで既存プロジェクトをEclipseへインポートする際、「ワークスペースへコピー」にチェックを入れたときだけ、ライブラリを読み込めない

Tags: android

Androidで既存プロジェクトをEclipseへインポートする際、「ワークスペースへコピー」にチェックを入れたときだけ、ライブラリを読み込めなくなるのですが、なぜでしょうか？
・「外部jar」もしくは「プロジェクト」の「パス」か「何か」をどこかで指定しないといけないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

既存のプロジェクトの相対パスでライブラリを持っていた場合、パスを設定し直さないといけません。
プロジェクトプロパティのAndroidの項やJava Build Pathを確認してください。

Answer (score 1):

プロジェクトを右クリック→プロパティ→Androidと辿ってライブラリーのところに緑のチェックが入っていないものを選んで削除します。
その後「追加」をクリックして、再度ライブラリーを読み直します。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

参考：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167273/in-eclipse-unable-to-reference-an-android-library-project-in-another-android-pr